# Align and size mapview window in Rmarkdown ioslides

Tags: r, r-sf, r-mapview

I'm trying to both center and resize the interactive map window from mapview in an Rmarkdown ioslides presentation - so far no luck.  A simple example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: ""
date: ""
output: ioslides_presentation
---

## Slide 2 
```{r echo=F, message=F, warning=FALSE, fig.align='center'}
library(sf)
library(mapview)
nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)
mapview(nc)
```
````

I'm guessing I need to apply a top-level css style customization to the document, but I'm not quite sure how to go about - any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center add center tags above and below the code chunk. Then adjust size using the `fig.width` and `fig.height` arguments.

````
## Slide 2 
<center>
```{r echo=F, message=F, warning=FALSE, fig.width=4}
library(sf)
library(mapview)
nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)
mapview(nc)
```
</center>
````

[image]

Comment: saddly, this solution do not seems to work with reveal.js slides.

Comment: oups, actually, this solution _seems_ to work with reveal.js slides as well.